# Adding HTML and Image-Based Signature in Wix Emails

Tags: velo

I’m currently using Wix for my website and email services, and I’m facing a challenge with customizing my email signature. I’m looking to create a signature that includes both HTML elements and images (like social media icons), but I’m unsure how to implement this in Wix.

I need some options if this can be done via code or a third party app within the wix editor.

The current option of adding a signature in the setting allows only text to be added and i want a more customized signature.

Thank you